# what is the difference between kendo UI and knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have worked with kendo ui but it's paid so some people suggest me to go for knockout.js. I am new in web developing. It will be really helpful if someone give tell me a the difference between kendo ui and knockout js.

Comment: Plenty of articles pop up if you google, like this one: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2013/04/08/comparing-kendoui-and-knockout-with-a-bit-of-jquerymobile-on-the-side.html

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Knockout has magic properties, Kendo has magic objects!
- Knockout is more flexible regarding view model construction
- Kendo requires a little effort to make it work with Intellisense
- Knockout supports view model hierarchies
- Kendo bindings are not JavaScript!
- Kendo lacks a $data binding
- Kendo has its own UI widgets!
- Kendo UI does not mangle the DOM
- jQM has a more extensive set of styles
- Kendo supports multiple mobile themes
- Kendo has a datasource concept
- Knockout is open source, Kendo costs $$$

for more information visit [Difference between kendo and knockout](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2013/04/08/comparing-kendoui-and-knockout-with-a-bit-of-jquerymobile-on-the-side.html)

Comment: Decent list. Re the last point; Kendo UI Core is open source and free to use, containing most widgets, albeit missing some of the more complex ones such as the Grid.